# Positiveness of the largest Lyapunov exponent

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ds.dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Let $\alpha\in \mathbb{R} / \mathbb{Q}$, let $A(x)$ be the $2$-by-$2$ matrix
$$
A(x)=\begin{pmatrix}
\dfrac{1}{{\lambda}^2}-2 \cos  2\pi x -1& 2\lambda \cos  2\pi x-\dfrac{1}{{\lambda}} \\
\dfrac{1}{{\lambda}} & -1
\end{pmatrix},
$$
and for $n\ge1$, let
$$
A_{n}(x)=A\bigl(x+(n-1) \alpha\bigr)\cdot  A\bigl(x+(n-2) \alpha\bigr) \cdots A(x+\alpha)\cdot A(x).
$$
The Lyapunov exponent (LE) of $(\alpha, A)$ at $\lambda\in\mathbb R_{>0}$ is given by
\begin{equation}
\operatorname{LE}(\lambda)=\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n} \int_{\mathbb{R} / \mathbb{Z}} \ln \bigl\|A_{n}(x)\bigr\| d x.
\end{equation}
How can one prove that when $\lambda>0$ is large enough, the Lyapunov exponent satisfies
$$\operatorname{LE}(\lambda) > 0? $$

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the main result of the paper of Michael Herman "Une méthode pour minorer..." https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02564647 in order to show that LE is positive when $\lambda$ is sufficiently large.

Comment: The Micheal Herman method can only get the Lyapunov exponent here to be greater than or equal to zero, but what I need here is greater than zero.